# How can I set the default working directory when opening a new terminal with VS Code?

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code with the integrated terminal.

When opening a new terminal in a workspace with multiple folders, I always receive a prompt saying:

```
Select current working directory for new terminal
```

How do I remove this prompt i.e. Set the default to always use the directory of the first folder?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can do this using the `terminal.integrated.cwd` setting. You can set it in your user `settings.json` file or your workspace's `.vscode/settings.json` file.

It supports variable substitution. See the list of available variables here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_predefined-variables.

Some examples of variables you can use: `${workspaceFolder}`, `${fileWorkspaceFolder}`, `${fileDirname}`, `${selectedText}`.

It seems that not *all* the directory variables are supported. For example, `userHome` doesn't work for me on my machine.

See also the `terminal.integrated.splitCwd` setting.

You may also be interested in the `workbench.action.terminal.newInActiveWorkspace` keybinding command.

---

If the terminal is opened for a task, then use the task's `options` property object's `cwd` property ([docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks)).